# Drawable not visible when camera preview is present

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera

I'm writing an app that requires displaying a semi-transparent PNG layer over a camera preview. Everything was fine until I wanted to publish it and make sure it works also on Android 2.x. It seems that on older versions of Android, the camera preview causes the drawable (in my case, a subclass of ImageView) to not show. When I get rid of the preview, it works just fine - the drawable is visible as it should. It works like this both on the emulator and on real devices.

Here how it looks like on Android 2.3:

[image: Image 1]

and 4.2.2:

[image: Image 2]

I think there would be too much code to paste here, so I've isolated the problematic parts into a small project: http://krzeminski.it/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/DrawableTest.zip. The most interesting and probably guilty class is **CameraPreview**.

Also, I'm not sure why the preview itself doesn't work. I've read that on Android 2.x emulators, the test image from the emulated camera is just this plain white, so I assumed it's ok. However, my friend tested the app on his phone with Android 2.3 and the preview appeared to be plain black. I guess it's a subject for a separate question, but maybe you'll notice something in the code.

I've spent probably 2 days now to solve these two problems, so any clues would be really helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue a while back. I remember that a post on SO recommended that you shouldn't use `ImageView#getImageMatrix()`. Reasoning given was:

**public Matrix getImageMatrix ():**

> Return the view's optional matrix. This is applied to the view's
>   drawable when it is drawn. If there is not matrix, this method will
>   return an identity matrix. Do not change this matrix in place but make
>   a copy. If you want a different matrix applied to the drawable, be
>   sure to call setImageMatrix().

Even after reading through this, I couldn't/don't understand what difference this makes. I sorted the problem out by using:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
```

May be you're dealing with the same issue. Give this a try.

Comment: Thank you, that was it! The preview is still not visible, but that's another problem.

Comment: @PiotrK You are welcome. By the way, if you are not seeing the preview on 2.3, that's (I think) by default. You won't get the same preview screen as you see on 4.2.2. To confirm this, fire up the 2.3 emulator, open all apps view, choose/launch Camera. You'll see what I mean.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not it. The preview may be black or white on 2.x, but my friend checked it on a real 2.3.3 device and he also couldn't see anything. What's more, he COULD take a photo. I can't believe there's no working example of camera preview for Android 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Android 2.3 device. But I think probably you can try two ways:
1. change FrameLayout to RelativeLayout
2. programmatically add views:

```
mLayout.addView(mPreview);
mLayout.addView(mImageView);
mLayout.addView(mTextView);
```